# How to read and edit CSV file using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I want to read a CSV file in Java Swing and then modify it; for instance I want to add some extra columns, a column that contains the ip address of the computer on which I am working and some more columns. Can anyone help me?

I am working on a project which reads the CSV file, modifies it and then loads that CSV file into a MySQL database. I have tried almost all tutorials but couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: you have to read the csv file, create another csv file with modified data. delete the old file and rename the new file.

Comment: *"I have tried almost all tutorials but couldnt find any solution."*  I think the problem is you are looking for too specific a tutorial.  What were the 5 closest hits?  I would not imagine there would be any single tutorial mentioning both CSV and Swing.

Comment: its not duplicate i also want to modify the csv file after reading it and then store it in the database.

Comment: @user3599030 So look up how to write to files and figure it out, instead of having us do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a CSV is independent from Swing: Swing handle user interfaces but not file input/output. For that, you can use the classes in the java.io package. In particular:

- the FileReader class to read through your file
- the BufferedReader class to read one line of your CSV file at a time
- the StringTokenizer class to parse individual entries in a line (part of java.util)

Then, the easiest way to display this with swing is to store this information inside nested Vector objects (java.util):

- one top level Vector where each element represents a line and is itself a Vector
- each Vector representing a line contains the entries for that line

From there, you can create a JTable (javax.swing) to display this information using the constructor

```
public JTable(Vector rowData, Vector columnNames)
```

You can see it requires yet another Vector with the names for each column (which must be the same size as the number of entries in a line from your file).

Comment: Please use generics when they're available -- i.e. `Vector<String>` instead of `Vector`. In this case, the JTable constructor doesn't take them, but since you can pass a `Vector<String>` where a `Vector` is required, that's how you should be storing them.